# Change the executable name after compiling Python code with cx_freeze

Tags: python, executable, py2exe, cx-freeze

I've been trying to get a small aplication I wrote in Python to work as a standalone program in any computer running Windows, so I tried to do so using both cx_freeze and py2exe.
Py2exe works fine and dandy but I really prefered using cx_freeze because of some compatibility issues.

The problem with cx_freeze, however, is that **after** compiling the code and all its dependencies, I can't change the executable's name (which is perfectly doable with py2exe).

So, say I have a simple `hello.py` script:

```
print ("Hello World! ")
raw_input ("Press any key to exit. \n")
```

and my `cxfreeze_setup.py`, which I copied directly from their website for debugging purposes, looks something like this:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


setup(  name = "hello",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My simple hello world!!",
        executables = [Executable("hello.py")])
```

When I build the standalone calling `python cxfreeze_setup.py build` in the command prompt, everything goes well and as expected, and the executable plus its dependencies are created in the usual `build` folder.

If I don't do any name changes to the `hello.exe` created and run it then everything runs perfectly aswell!

However, say I change the `hello.exe` to `hey.exe`. Now, when I try to run `hey.exe` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26 in <module>
code = importer.get_code(moduleName)
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't find module 'hey__main__'
```

If I change the `.exe` name to `hi.exe` then the error stays exactly same except for the last line where it now says `can't find module 'hi__main__'`

Finally, I was wondering if, with cx_freeze, I'm forced to not change the executable name after compiling it and, if that's not the case, what modifications to either my `hello.py` or `cxfreeze_setup.py` scripts must I perform in order to freely modify the executable name after being compiled, something I can perfectly do with py2exe.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You could always use a shortcut to the `.exe`. Doesn't actually solve your problem, but could be a way around it.

Comment: Daniel, If you find my answer helpful, please accept it thank you.

Comment: The exe cx_Freeze makes uses its own name to look up the Python script to run. The advatage of this is that you can have multiple exes sharing a set of libraries. The downside is that you can't easily rename exes. If you do need to, open up `library.zip`, and rename `hello__main__.pyc` to `hey__main__.pyc` (the first bit matching your exe).

Comment: @laike9m Laike I appreciate your help but I already knew how to change the executable's name **before** being compiled. If you re-read my question you'll find I wanted to know how to do it after being compiled, which was/is when I'm getting the error I described.
As such, I cannot accept your answer because it doesn't actually solve my specific problem. Still, I appreciate your help and effort.

Comment: @ThomasK So that explains **why** I cannot rename the executable. It's also good to know that I **can** change the executable name, just have to mess a bit with the `__main__` code method. Thanks for the tips, I guess that could be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

The exe cx_Freeze makes uses its own name to look up the Python script to run. The advatage of this is that you can have multiple exes sharing a set of libraries. The downside is that you can't easily rename exes.

If you do need to rename the exe, open up library.zip, and rename `hello__main__.pyc` to `hey__main__.pyc` (the first bit should match your exe's name).

Answer (score 3):

Use `--target-name=NAME`, Quote from [doc](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/script.html#cmdoption--target-name):

> --target-name=NAME
>   the name of the file to create instead of the base name of the script and the extension of the base binary

Or just:

```
setup(name = "guifoo",
      version = "0.1",
      description = "My GUI application!",
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables = [Executable("guifoo.py", base=base, targetName="what_you_want.exe")])
```

Comment: What did you do? I've actually tried this and it worked perfect. Use `python setup.py build` to compile.

Comment: @DanielShaw OK, so first, read the doc, there must be something you did wrong. And DO NOT change the filename manually, the executable should be named `what_you_want` when it's generated.

Comment: I ran the exact same script as you've posted, just changed the base =  base statement because this is a console application. I can change the .exe name output, I was just wondering if, after compiling it, I could change the .exe name manually. I can do that with py2exe.

Comment: @DanielShaw I tried changing its name after compiling and got the error. It seems cx_freeze won't let you do this, which is kind of weird.

Comment: Ah see! That was the error I was getting. Weird, ain't it? py2exe let's you change the exec name to whatever you want, as long as you keep all the dependencies in the same folder, so I wonder what cx_freeze does to not let you do that.

Comment: @DanielShaw Yeah I agree. But since you can name it in `setup.py`, it really doesn't matter(at least for me) that I can't change it after compiling.

Comment: @DanielShaw I'm going to sleep, hope my answer could be accpted :)

Answer (score 1):

For the python scripted version the camelCase `targetName=`, does not work.

```
    setup(name = "guifoo",
  version = "0.1",
  description = "My GUI application!",
  options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
  executables = [Executable("guifoo.py", base=base, targetName="what_you_want.exe")])enter code here
```

However, `target_name=` does.

```
    setup(name = "guifoo",
  version = "0.1",
  description = "My GUI application!",
  options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
  executables = [Executable("guifoo.py", base=base, target_name="what_you_want.exe")])
```